# "Rate limit reached for requests" from all ChatInput requests, even on the very first use of the API

Tags: serviceexecute

I had hoped to use the new LLM features in Mathematica 13.3. I requested an API key from OpenAI and gave it to Mathematica; the API key has never been used for anything else. Per OpenAI, it allows 3 requests per minute or 40,000 tokens per minute for GPT 3.5.

`ServiceConnect["OpenAI"]` connects but any request via `ServiceExecute[openAI,…]`, or a ChatInput cell, or ChatQuery, or ChatSystemInput results in a "You have exceeded your current quote" error.

Is anybody able to get these features working?

Comment: Just tried everything everyone here recommended and still got the "...exceeded your current quota..." message with a never-before-used key.

Answer (score 1):

I only succeeded with a paid plan.
You should first test to OpenAI exporting the OPENAI_API_KEY variable and test it with the following curl
`$ curl https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions   -H "Content-Type: application/json"   -H "Authorization: Bearer $OPENAI_API_KEY"   -d '{ "model": "gpt-3.5-turbo", "messages": [{"role": "user", "content": "Say this is a test!"}], "temperature": 0.7 }'`

If successful it will return the following and it will work in Mathematica

```
{
  "id": "chatcmpl-7lzRf746q3B2JWJ252bWTlkiJcYw5",
  "object": "chat.completion",
  "created": 1691671967,
  "model": "gpt-3.5-turbo-0613",
  "choices": [
    {
      "index": 0,
      "message": {
        "role": "assistant",
        "content": "This is a test!"
      },
      "finish_reason": "stop"
    }
  ],
  "usage": {
    "prompt_tokens": 13,
    "completion_tokens": 5,
    "total_tokens": 18
  }
}
```